# Indenting part of a list

Tags: lists, indentation

So I'm trying to indent a list that I have to look something like

```
2)
    1) random stuff
    2) random stuff
```

I'm using

```
    \item[2)]
        \hfill \item[1)]Hello World
```

but it isn't working for me. I still get `1)` to be directly under `2)` which I want `1)` to be tabbed out a little bit to show that the list is starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question I believe you require \subitem here is a minimal code to see if it is what you would desire.

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Normal
    \item Normal
      \subitem Indented
      \subitem Indented
      \subitem Indented
    \item Back to normal
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This gives

[image: Result]

Comment: `\subitem` is used in the `theindex` environment and its behavior is unpredictable elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

This is straight-forward with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newlist{numbered}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[numbered]{label={\arabic*)}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{numbered}
    \item First
    \item Second
      \begin{numbered}
        \item Sub-first
        \item Sub-second
        \item Sub-third
      \end{numbered}
    \item Third
  \end{numbered}
\end{document}
```

The list `numbered` above emulates `enumerate` with a specific `label` (having a right-parenthesis) and exactly 2 levels.

For an empty `Second`, use `\mbox{}`.